# daterangepicker date limit for minimum date

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Is there any option for daterangepicker to select maximum of 60 days of dates and minimum of 10 days of dates. I see an option of having `dateLimit`, which only set the limit for given number. Not for minimum and maximum days of dates. 
Means, I want user to select maximum 60 days or minimum of 10 days of dates.
I tries to search on google, but didn't find anything other that `dateLimit`.
Does anybody knows how to handle this?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know which daterangepicker you are using, but i guess you can write a simple callback on one of it's events and check the current selected values against your conditions yourself.

Comment: Thanks @lapskaus. I am using this from daterangepicker.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this example because you have to use `moment.js` for the daterangepicker of [daterangepicker.com](https://www.daterangepicker.com/). All available options of the daterangepickeryou can find [here](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#options).

For working with `momentjs` you find more informations [here](https://momentjs.com/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    // you can use this optionally -> maxSpan: 50
    minDate: moment().add(10, 'days').calendar(),
    maxDate: moment().add(60, 'days').calendar()
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="daterange" />
```